# Flex pass object to component by event

Tags: apache-flex

I need to call a component and pass an object. Now I am using event initialize to pass into the method of component but it seem to execute only once as follows. Is there anyway that I can make it call every time it loads.
initialize="parentApplication.projectView.projectDetails.loadProject(newProject)">

```
<mx:TabNavigator id="tn" x="38" y="10"  >
    <s:NavigatorContent label="List Matter" width="100%" >
        <view:ProjectList id="projectList" LoadRecord="loadRecordHandler(event)">

        </view:ProjectList>


    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent label="Matter" width="100%" >
        <view:ProjectDetails id="projectDetails" initialize="parentApplication.mainView.projectView.projectDetails.loadProject(newProject)">

        </view:ProjectDetails>
        <mx:LinkButton x="594" y="10" label="Set Matter Permission"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
```

Comment: Define what "Call a component" means.  You need to execute a method inside a component?  Or set a property?  Or something else?  Teh initialize event is part of the Flex Component LifeCycle and will only dispatch once during the component's 'life'.  What do you mean when you say "every time it loads"?  Generally a component only loads once per instance.  If you want to run code every time it is displayed, use the show evnt?  IF you want to run code Every time the component display changes use updateComplete.

Answer (score 0):

if you need an event that is called every time your component becomes active - try some of the following:

```
add, added, addedToStage, show
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try *show* event, if I understand you